# Cos'è un "lòffaro"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Corre sulle piattaforme della soprelevata col fascio di giornali sottobraccio – imprendibile ai tutori dell’ordine e ai bigliettai, molestissimo ai clienti, piú di una zanzara. Ha imparato ad aggredire gli impiegati quando escono dagli uffici e a godere del loro odio impotente di borghesucci atterriti dalla sua sfacciatissima insistenza. A sfidare i **lòffari** contendendogli un passaggio sui treni merci diretti ai depositi, e i murphy a sassate – mirando sempre alla testa, dove fa piú male.

Sapreste dirmi cos'è un "lòffaro"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Comment: Da quanto ho letto su [questo articolo sui *Primi Poemetti* di Pascoli](https://www.academia.edu/32280535/I_Primi_poemetti_di_Giovanni_Pascoli_nellelaborazione_autografa_Nuova_Rivista_di_Letteratura_italiana_XII_2009_pp._105-151), sembra si tratti di un vocabolo italo-americano.

Comment: Se ne parla anche su [questo articolo](http://ojs.pensamultimedia.it/index.php/pl/article/viewFile/1306/1271) (ho dovuto leggerlo nella copia cache di Google).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da un paio di articoli che studiano la stesura dei *Primi poemetti* di Giovanni Pascoli ho potuto imparare che si tratta di un termine italo-americano, più concretamente della deformazione da parte degli emigrati italiani negli Stati Uniti del vocabolo inglese "loafer", che significa "fannullone", "perdigiorno", "scansafatiche". Questo vocabolo appare in un manoscrito di Giovanni Pascoli, in un elenco di lemmi italo-americani che l'autore aveva fatto quando stava elaborando il poema *Italy*, ma poi non l'ha adoperato nel testo definitivo del poema.

Nell'articolo ["I *Primi poemetti* di Giovanni Pascoli nell'elaborazione autografa"](https://www.academia.edu/32280535/I_Primi_poemetti_di_Giovanni_Pascoli_nellelaborazione_autografa_Nuova_Rivista_di_Letteratura_italiana_XII_2009_pp._105-151), di Francesca Nassi, apparso nella *Nuova Rivista di Letteratura italiana*, XII (2009) si può leggere:

> Il manoscritto LI, 13, f. 2 riflette con chiarezza la situazione di partenza
>   della stesura di *Italy*: contiene un elenco di *Odi* e uno di *Inni*, uno schema stagionale riferito alla vicenda georgica dei *Nuovi Poemetti* e l’incipit di *Italy* («Era una
>   fosca sera di febbraio./ Gente saliva l’erta di Caprona./ Da *US.* veniva,
>   *Cincinnati, Ohio*») e per il resto è completamente riempito da un fitto repertorio
>   di lemmi in italo-americano, frutto delle inchieste linguistiche condotte direttamente da Pascoli presso la famiglia di Isabella. Non limitandosi a singole parole (come «dego», «lòffaro», «vaghino» e così via), toponimi («Francolino»)
>   o espressioni (come «son of bitch»), accompagnate talvolta dalla pronuncia («sanababicci») o dal presunto originale inglese («*sohn of beach*»), Pascoli annota intere frasi e modi di dire, nella ricerca di echi della vita vissuta dagli emigrati in America.

Sul termine "lòffaro" una nota a piè di pagina in questo articolo spiega:

> Lòffaro < loafer (PERUGI, *Fra estetica e linguistica…*). La voce è presente in ALDO BERTOZZI, *Dizionario garfagnino*, Lucca, Maria Pacini Fazzi 2007, con il significato «vagabondo, indolente, pigro».

Anche l'articolo "Giovanni Pascoli, *Primi poemetti*, a cura di F. Nassi, Edizione Nazionale delle opere di Giovanni Pascoli, Bologna, Pàtron Editore" apparso nella rubrica "Cronache" del numero 23 della 
rivista [*Per leggere*](http://www.italinemo.it/riviste/dettaglio_rivista.php?Titolo=PER%20LEGGERE) (autunno 2012) ci dà queste informazioni:

> Fra i rilievi linguistici (per i quali la curatrice si affida anche a precedenti studi lessicologici), segnalerei almeno tutte quelle note utilissime che in *Italy* accompagnano i termini inglesi, deformati dagli emigrati garfagnini di prima generazione come Beppe (Molly parla invece nella nuova e per diverso tempo sua unica lingua), di cui rimangono a testo definitivo solo alcuni casi («pai con fleva», «bisini», «fruttistendo», «checche», «candi», «scrima», ecc.), ma che sono invece molto numerosi negli abbozzi: la Nassi si affida principalmente allo studio specifico di Perugi (cfr. M. Perugi *Fra estetica e linguistica. La lingua degli emigranti nel poemetto Italy*, in *Seconda lettura pascoliana urbinate*, a cura di G. Cerboni Baiardi, A. Oldcorn e T. Mattioli,
>   Fondazione Cassa di Risparmio di Pesaro, Pesaro, Il lavoro editoriale, 2003, pp. 149-
>   69), ma anche a strumenti lessicologici, come quelli di Haller e Bertozzi (cfr. H.W. Haller, *Una lingua perduta e ritrovata. L’italiano degli italo-americani*, Firenze, La Nuova Italia, 1993; A. Bertozzi, *Dizionario garfagnino*, Lucca, Maria Pacini Fazzi, 2007), non solo, direi, per offrire una spiegazione del termine deformato, il cui originale non è sempre facilmente intuibile («lòffaro» da *loafer*, «vaghino» da *wagon*, «pulizio» da *police*, «Francolino» da *Franklin*, «sceppe» da *shop*, «smalto» da *smart*, «orsi» da *horse*, ecc.), ma per garantire anche al lettore la giustezza della propria trascrizione.