# Cosa vuol dire "connellare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita non ha mai avuto una bambola, perché poteva sempre **connellare** il figlio di una vicina o di una parente. Anche a Prince Street cambiava i pannolini al figlio della vicina Melchiorra Corpora, un neonato rachitico che chiaramente non sarebbe sopravvissuto all’inverno, e infatti è morto una notte di dicembre, lasciando Vita senza giocattolo, a urlare che voleva tornare a casa sua. Quel giorno gli era venuto in mente di farle una bambola.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato del verbo "connellare" che appare in questo passaggio del romanzo? Immagino che sia un vocabolo di origine regionale perché non l'ho trovato su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato, neanche sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*.

Dovete sapere che i protagonisti di questo romanzo sono emigrati italiani a New York, provenienti concretamente da Minturno, che spesso usano meridionalismi e anche vocaboli italo-amaricani, come si può vedere per esempio [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10265/707).

Comment: Puoi specificare capitolo e pagina del brano, per favore?

Comment: @abarisone:    Avevo un'edizione cartacea che ho presa di una biblioteca, ma ho dovuto restiturla e in questo momento non l'ho con me. Adesso ho comprato una versione e-book e il brano appare nel capitolo intitolato "Le scarpe nuove di Cesare Cuzzopuoti".

Comment: Non l'ho mai sentito... immagino significhi "accudire"

Comment: Questo libro, se ho ben capito, usa un italiano gergale pieno di meridionalismi ed espressioni colloquiali tipiche degli italo-americani (e, sospetto, anche qualcuna inventata). Mi chiedo (e non è una domanda retorica) se possa essere utile, in questi casi, specificare la particolarità nella domanda.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: fatto.

Comment: Cercando su Google “Vita Melania Mazzucco connellare” ho trovato il riferimento a questo testo sulla lingua dei libri vincitori dello Strega dal 2002 al 2009: https://www.torrossa.com/en/resources/an/2463930. Purtroppo non riesco a scaricarlo gratuitamente. Nell’anteprima dei risultati di Google si legge che secondo questo testo «connellare» significa «cullare».

Comment: A quanto pare, @Benedetta ha trovato il significato. Su questo [*Dizionario del dialetto torrese con citazioni dalla letteratura napoletana*](https://www.academia.edu/11015218/Lettera_-_C_-_Dizionario_del_dialetto_torrese_con_citazioni_dalla_letteratura_napoletana), di Salvatore Argenziano, si trova "cunnüliá" col significato di "cullare".

Comment: @Charo: sono contenta che siamo arrivate a trovare il significato!

Answer (score 2):

A quanto pare, "connellare" provviene dal napoletano "cunnulià" che, da quanto si può leggere su questa [*Grammatica diacronica del napoletano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=jsHJnzvJHxAC&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=cunnuli%C3%A0+cullare&source=bl&ots=wjr8TJA4-v&sig=ACfU3U3dmxiS5mWvZWmaLh6wR9dYG0kTVg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViabui4DjAhUcSxUIHZJIASYQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cunnuli%C3%A0%20cullare&f=false), di Adam Ledgeway, significa "cullare". Tale significato viene anche riportato nel libro [*Poesie napoletane per le scuole elementari e medie*](https://books.google.es/books?id=ao_jAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=cunnuli%C3%A0+cullare&source=bl&ots=_XWY97NTPd&sig=ACfU3U2MNiZdYecdS1lRhEGY2mu3wTnwoQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjow8bDiYDjAhWM2hQKHVSQACIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cunnuli%C3%A0%20cullare&f=false), che spiega che "cunnulià" viene dal termine napoletano "connola", che significa "culla" e  «deriva dalla saldatura delle parole "cuna" e "dòndola".» Si trova anche su questo [*Dizionario del dialetto torrese con citazioni dalla letteratura napoletana*](https://www.academia.edu/11015218/Lettera_-_C_-_Dizionario_del_dialetto_torrese_con_citazioni_dalla_letteratura_napoletana), di Salvatore Argenziano:

> **cunnüliá:**              *v. tr.* Cullare. 
>               
>   *RDS. m’ha pigliato pe’ sott’ ’e brazze 
>               
>   e s’è mmiso a cunnulia’ 
>               
>   Cunnulianno sta fantasia 
>               
>   viene ’a ccà oi nenna mia

Comment: Veramente, se ho trovato questo significato è stato grazie al commento di @Benedetta, a cui voglio ringraziare.