# Che cos'è un "cacarone"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Rocco sorride. Ancora una volta ha visto bene. Non è facile pescare un ragazzino sveglio, in questo quartiere di pecore. **Cacaroni** capaci solo di farsi mangiare dal lupo – di subire. Gente che s’accorgerebbe che in cielo c’è la luna solo se questa gli cadesse in testa.

Non ho trovato il termine "cacarone" sui dizionari che ho consultato. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa? Sospetto che sia un termine di uso regionale, probabilmente collegato col napoletano, perché i protagonisti di questo romanzo sono emigrati italiani a New York, provenienti concretamente da Minturno, e ho letto su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minturno) che il dialetto minturnese deriva dalla lingua napoletana.

Comment: A quanto pare, nel libro [*Chi è stregato dallo Strega? Rilievi di stile sugli ultimi romanzi vincitori (2002-2009)*](https://www.torrossa.com/en/resources/an/2463930), indicato da @Benedetta nel suo [commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10608/cosa-vuol-dire-connellare#comment24866_10608), appare anche questo significato. Nell'anteprima di Google indicata da Benedetta si può leggere la parola "cacaroni", ma non riesco a vedere il significato.

Comment: Adesso sono riuscita a vederlo: cercando su Google "connellare “cullare” (p. 100); cacaroni" ho trovato nell'anteprima che mostra Google «connellare “cullare” (p. 100); cacaroni “vigliacchi” (p. 101);​». Quindi, il significato di "cacaroni" sarebbe “vigliacchi”.

Comment: Più comune sarebbe *cacasotto*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo [dizionario di dialetto salentino](http://www.dialettosalentino.it/cacarone.html) il termine *cacarone* viene così definito:

> **cacarone**
>  significato in italiano: persona che defeca in abbondanza; (traslato)  cacasotto, persona vile, codarda.
> etimologia:  cacare.
>
> sinonimi o termini collegati: paurusu, timusu.
>  contrari:
> coraggiusu

Come suggerito da @egreg il termine comune sarebbe *cacasotto*.

Answer (score 4):

Il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* non riporta la voce "cacarone", ma sì quella di ["cacasótto"](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_480.pdf) con questo significato:

> **Cacasótto,** sm. Invar. Spreg. Vigliacco, pusil­lanime; buono a nulla; chi si confonde alle prime difficoltà.

Più avanti in questa stessa voce si trova una citazione dal *Vocabolario domestico napoletano e toscano* (Napoli, 1841) di [Basilio Puoti](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI_indice_autori/GDLI_Indice_autori_238.pdf) nella quale si legge:

> *Cacarone* o *cacasotto*, voce  bassa  ed  ingiuriosa con cui si rimprovera altrui la sua timidità e poltroneria.

Quindi, come menzionato da @egreg nel suo commento, "cacarone" sarebbe un sinonimo di "cacasotto" con il significato spiegato sopra.

Anche sul [*Vocabolario napoletano lessigrafico e storico*](https://books.google.es/books?id=HRK5Tw5COm0C&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=cacarone+dizionario&source=bl&ots=yH6cTyha_K&sig=ACfU3U32VsjH_NFevxG1PRGv798WPCVbJg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl4Na7sILjAhXnUBUIHU0_CRwQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cacarone%20dizionario&f=false) (Napoli, 1845) di Vincenzio De Ritis si trova:

> **Cacarone** (*agg*.) Timido, vile, persona da nulla. 
>               
>   *Ma primmo vò chella saetta franca 
>
>               
>   De Pannaro trovà pe la barruffa, 
>
>               
>   Non pecchè a isso spirito lle manca 
>
>               Ca maie de cacarone ha dato muffa*, ec. Om. V, 38.